# What is the git command used by gitlab on merge requests to show changes?

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlabs merge requests have a 'changes' button which shows exactly the changes that will happen to the target branch if the merge is accepted.

I would like to be able to see that information on the commandline, without having to create a merge request.

Comment: Did you mean git-diff?

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 1):

It would simply be `git diff target..proposedMerge` I think

For your command line purposes target and proposedMerge can be:

- sha1 of commits
- branch names (locally, like "master", or remote, like "origin/develop" <--- don't forget to `git fetch` first !)
- relative position on branch names, like master~2, or HEAD^

For output visualisation, there are various plugins available for git diff, you can pick one you like if you don't like the default one !

Comment: That works, but only if there has been no changes to the target branch since I merged it into my work branch.

Comment: For "branch name", I also meant for example `origin/develop` as a possibility, for comparing with a remote one :) Which I think avoids the problem you mention. I refined my answer accordingly !

Comment: I tested it with origon/develop and that gave the same issue. However using tripple dots did give me what I wanted.

Comment: Well, I must have misunderstood your question or git, since I thought triple dots don't refer to the HEAD of a given branch ^^ But anyway, I'm glad you figured a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This is clearer with [GitLab 13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#merge-refs-for-changes-in-merge-requests) (February 2021)

> ### Merge Refs for changes in merge requests
>
> Merge request diffs have been calculated by `git diff target...source` which compares `HEAD` of the target with the merge base of `target` and `source`. This works well, until changes from the target branch are merged into the source branch, creating a complete mess of the diff.
>
> **Merge requests now compare to `<default branch> (HEAD)` by default when viewing the changes tab of a merge request**.
> This provides a more accurate and up-to-date diff of the changes during your review.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/versions.html#head-comparison-mode-for-merge-requests) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/854).

In particular:

Before, as noted in [issue 15140](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/15140#note_11709832), it was `git diff from...to`:

> The reason why we use `git diff from...to` instead of `git diff from to`, is that the latter with include all differences between the heads of the two branches, which means that any changes that were made to the target branch (`from`) after the source branch (`to`) was created, will show up as deletions in the diff.
>
> In the majority of cases, `git diff from...to` is exactly what we want, but since it compares using the merge base, not the actual commit content, it does not handle cherry-picks correctly.

After: see "[Merge request diffs against the HEAD of the target branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/diffs.html#merge-request-diffs-against-the-head-of-the-target-branch)"

> Consider the following case, in which the source branch is `feature_a` and the target is `master`:
>
> - Checkout a new branch `feature_a` from `master` and remove `file_a` and `file_b` in it.
> - Add a commit that removes `file_a` to `master`.
>
> The merge request diff still contains the `file_a` removal while the actual diff compared to master’s HEAD has only the `file_b` removal.
> The diff with such redundant changes is harder to review.
>
> In order to display an up-to-date diff, in [GitLab 12.9 we introduced](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27008) merge request diffs compared against HEAD of the target branch: the target branch is artificially merged into the source branch, then the resulting merge ref is compared to the source branch in order to calculate an accurate diff.